# swap hex binary with rule

Tags: file, binary, swap

please i need a how to do in linux for swap job.

my exemple :

9882 swaped to 016C

and

3030 swaped to 0303

like this

1001 1000 1000 0010 = 9882  : bin

0000 0001 0110 1100 = 016C  : bin swap

bin before swap :

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F

1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0

bin after swap :

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F

0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0

with swap rule :

bin_SWAP[0] = bin[D];

bin_SWAP[1] = bin[5];

bin_SWAP[2] = bin[6];

bin_SWAP[3] = bin[7];

bin_SWAP[4] = bin[9];

bin_SWAP[5] = bin[1];

bin_SWAP[6] = bin[2];

bin_SWAP[7] = bin[3];

bin_SWAP[8] = bin[C];

bin_SWAP[9] = bin[4];

bin_SWAP[A] = bin[E];

bin_SWAP[B] = bin[F];

bin_SWAP[C] = bin[8];

bin_SWAP[D] = bin[0];

bin_SWAP[E] = bin[A];

bin_SWAP[F] = bin[B];

there is any program in linux can swap a file with more than 64 bytes

my exmple do with 2 bytes.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

another exmple for more simplify

swap 4 bytes 
B455CBD5

---

B455

1011 0100 0101 0101     : bin

0123 4567 89AB CDEF     : position

1100 1011 0001 0101     : bin swap

CB15

---

CBD5

1100 1011 1101 0101     : bin

0123 4567 89AB CDEF     : position

1011 1100 0111 1101             : bin swap

BC7D

---

than the result is

CB15BC7D